# How to assure the return StringList will be ordered : Scala

Tags: scala

I am using Scala 2.11.8

I am trying to read queries from my Property File. Each Query Set has multiple parts (explained below)

And i have certain sequence in which these queries must execute.

**Code:**

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
    object ReadProperty {
      def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
        val queryRead = ConfigFactory.load("testqueries.properties").getConfig("select").getStringList("caseInc").toArray()

        val localRead = ConfigFactory.load("testqueries.properties").getConfig("select").getStringList("caseLocal").toArray.toSet

        queryRead.foreach(println)
        localRead.foreach(println)
      }
    }
```

**PropertyFile Content :**

```
select.caseInc.2 = Select emp_salary, emp_dept_id from employees
select.caseLocal.1 = select one
select.caseLocal.3 = select three
select.caseRemote.2 = Select e1.emp_name, d1.dept_name, e1.salary from emp_1 e1 join dept_1 d1 on(e1.emp_dept_id = d1.dept_id)
select.caseRemote.1 = Select * from departments
select.caseInc.1 = Select emp_id, emp_name from employees
select.caseLocal.2 = select two
select.caseLocal.4 = select four
```

**Output:**

```
Select emp_id, emp_name from employees
Select emp_salary, emp_dept_id from employees
select one
select two
select three
select four
```

As we can see in output, The result is **Sorted** . In the property if you see i have tried numbering the queries in the sequence it should run.(passing the caseInc, caseLocal as arguments).

With getStringList() i am always getting the Sorted List on the basis of the sequence number i am providing.

Even when i tried using toArray() & toArray().toSet i am getting sorted output.

**So far its Good**

But how to be sure that it will always return in Sorted Order which i have provided in the property file. I am confused because somehow i am not able to find the API which says that the returned List will be Sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rely on this fact. Looking into the code of [DefaultTransformer](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/f6680a5dad51d992139d45a84fad734f1778bf50/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/impl/DefaultTransformer.java#L83-L123) you can see following piece of logic:

```
    } else if (requested == ConfigValueType.LIST && value.valueType() == ConfigValueType.OBJECT) {
        // attempt to convert an array-like (numeric indices) object to a
        // list. This would be used with .properties syntax for example:
        // -Dfoo.0=bar -Dfoo.1=baz
        // To ensure we still throw type errors for objects treated
        // as lists in most cases, we'll refuse to convert if the object
        // does not contain any numeric keys. This means we don't allow
        // empty objects here though :-/
        AbstractConfigObject o = (AbstractConfigObject) value;
        Map<Integer, AbstractConfigValue> values = new HashMap<Integer, AbstractConfigValue>();
        for (String key : o.keySet()) {
            int i;
            try {
                i = Integer.parseInt(key, 10);
                if (i < 0)
                    continue;
                values.put(i, o.get(key));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (!values.isEmpty()) {
            ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, AbstractConfigValue>> entryList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, AbstractConfigValue>>(
                    values.entrySet());
            // sort by numeric index
            Collections.sort(entryList,
                    new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, AbstractConfigValue>>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, AbstractConfigValue> a,
                                Map.Entry<Integer, AbstractConfigValue> b) {
                            return Integer.compare(a.getKey(), b.getKey());
                        }
                    });
            // drop the indices (we allow gaps in the indices, for better or
            // worse)
            ArrayList<AbstractConfigValue> list = new ArrayList<AbstractConfigValue>();
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, AbstractConfigValue> entry : entryList) {
                list.add(entry.getValue());
            }
            return new SimpleConfigList(value.origin(), list);
        }
    }
```

Note how keys are parsed as integer values and then sorted using `Integer.compare`